# How to switch to desktop view on mobile when you are using Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am developed a website using responsive framework Zurb Foundation 4 a little ago.

Now my client requested to put a button which says "Switch to Desktop Version" and when it is clicked by visitor the site should behave like non-responsive or desktop version should do on a mobile.

I tried to find something similar in foundation 4 but did not succeed some solutions are just to remove media queries using javascript. Please remember Foundation 4 uses Mobile First... Can anyone please suggest some thing?

Comment: Could you use a `click` handler on the button to remove/hide the `Foundation 4` css file?

Comment: If I remove Foundation 4 css file, I have to write styles for desktop version again... which is I am afraid a lot work to do :(

Comment: or split up the styles that are used for mobile into another sheet and hide that.

Comment: again: it will take too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point you can manipulate the `viewport` meta-tag with js.

Originally it is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Add an `id` for easier reference and change the contents of the attribute `content` to something like `width=1280`:

```
document.getElementById("myViewportTag").setAttribute('content', 'width=1280, inital-scale=1.0')
```

**Note:** This only works on the current page and gets lost with the next page-load. But you could use cookies to preserve the preferences of a user and set the viewport on every page-load when the cookie is present.